# Micronaut Junit 5 testing of Post method falsely returns null

Tags: micronaut

I am using micronaut framework for my project. When doing a test for one of the post methods, I am returning null, instead of the response body. However, when i call the controller directly in the test method, all test work fine. Please see my controller and test code respectively.

Controller.Java

```
    @Post(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public HttpResponse<ResultAttemptDTO> save(@Body Response response) {

        User user = triviaService.checkUser(response.getUser());

        int isCorrect =  Utils.checkResponse(response);

        /*Creates a new resultAttempt */
        ResultAttempt resultAttempt = new ResultAttempt(
                user.getId(),
                LocalDateTime.now(),
                response.getQuestion(),
                response.getAnswer(),
                Utils.generateAttemptId(),
                isCorrect == 1 ? true: false);

        ResultAttempt result = triviaResultService.postTriviaResults(resultAttempt);

        gamificationClient.save(user.getId(), Utils.generateAttemptId(), isCorrect);

        ResultAttemptDTO resultAttemptDTO = Utils.resultAttemptDTO(resultAttempt);

        return HttpResponse.ok(resultAttemptDTO);
    }
```

TestController.Java

```
   @Test
    void testPostResultAttempt() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("name");
        user.setId(1l);

        Response response1 = new Response();
        response1.setAnswer("Trump");
        response1.setQuestion("Who is the president of the USA");
        response1.setChoices("Obama|Trump|Lincon");
        response1.setCorrectAnswer(1);
        response1.setUser(user);

        ResultAttempt resultAttempt = new ResultAttempt();
        resultAttempt.setAnswer("Trump");
        resultAttempt.setQuestion("Who is the president of the USA");
        resultAttempt.setLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        resultAttempt.setCorrect(true);
        resultAttempt.setUserId(1l);
        resultAttempt.setAttemptId(1);
        resultAttempt.setId(1l);

        Result result = new Result(1l, 1, 1);

        ResultAttemptDTO resultAttemptDTO = new ResultAttemptDTO(resultAttempt.getUserId(),
                Utils.dateFormat(LocalDateTime.now()), resultAttempt.getQuestion(), resultAttempt.getAnswer(),
                String.valueOf(resultAttempt.isCorrect()));

        when(triviaService.checkUser(user)).thenReturn(user);

        when(triviaResultService.postTriviaResults(resultAttempt))
                .thenReturn(resultAttempt);

        when(gamificationClient.save(resultAttempt.getUserId(), resultAttempt.getAttemptId(), 1))
                .thenReturn(result);

        HttpResponse<ResultAttemptDTO> response = client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.POST("results", response1));

        //HttpResponse<ResultAttemptDTO> response = trivialResultController.save(response1);

        System.out.println(response.body());

        assertEquals(response.body(), resultAttemptDTO);
        assertEquals(response.status(), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

The code

```
HttpResponse<ResultAttemptDTO> response = client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.POST("results", response1));
```

returns null when i should get the ResultAttemptDTO object.

Everything works fine with

```
HttpResponse<ResultAttemptDTO> response = trivialResultController.save(response1);
```

Any suggestions on why it is not working?

Comment: Have you tried `HttpRequest.POST("/results", response1)`? (notice the leading slash in `"/results"`)

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you are seeing but there are pieces missing from your question that might be relevant.  I have created a simple example similar to what you are doing at https://github.com/jeffbrown/codymanresponse. The controller is at https://github.com/jeffbrown/codymanresponse/blob/master/src/main/java/codymanresponse/ResultAttemptController.java and the test is at https://github.com/jeffbrown/codymanresponse/blob/master/src/test/java/codymanresponse/ResultAttemptControllerTest.java. If you can evolve that to simulate the error you are seeing, that would be helpful.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown thank you for your response. Please see my reply below for the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

everybody. I managed to solve the problem. The issue was I did not pass in the parameter of type any() into the mocked methods. Hence the issue. Please find my corrected code as follows:

```
    @Test
    void testPostResultAttempt() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("name");
        user.setId(1l);

        Response response1 = new Response();
        response1.setAnswer("Trump");
        response1.setQuestion("Who is the president of the USA");
        response1.setChoices("Obama|Trump|Lincon");
        response1.setCorrectAnswer(1);
        response1.setUser(user);

        ResultAttempt resultAttempt = new ResultAttempt();
        resultAttempt.setAnswer("Trump");
        resultAttempt.setQuestion("Who is the president of the USA");
        resultAttempt.setLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        resultAttempt.setCorrect(true);
        resultAttempt.setUserId(1l);
        resultAttempt.setAttemptId(1);
        resultAttempt.setId(1l);

        Result result = new Result(1l, 1, 1);

        ResultAttemptDTO resultAttemptDTO = new ResultAttemptDTO(resultAttempt.getUserId(),
                Utils.dateFormat(LocalDateTime.now()), resultAttempt.getQuestion(), resultAttempt.getAnswer(),
                String.valueOf(resultAttempt.isCorrect()));

        when(triviaService.checkUser(user)).thenReturn(user);

        when(triviaResultService.postTriviaResults(any(ResultAttempt.class)))
                .thenReturn(resultAttempt);

        when(gamificationClient.save(anyLong(), anyInt(), anyInt()))
                .thenReturn(result);

        HttpResponse<ResultAttemptDTO> response = client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.POST("/results", response1), ResultAttemptDTO.class);

        assertEquals(resultAttemptDTO, response.body());
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.status());
    }
```